# Hubby lost his (UK) passport in Germany yesterday and we are due to fly to the USA on Tuesday. Can he get a visa to go with his ETD?

Tags: visas, usa, lost-documents

My husband lost his passport in Germany yesterday (Thursday) he will be issued his Emergency Travel document from the UK embassy in Munich on Monday. Can anyone advise if he can get a visa to enter the US before Christmas? Would he be better off trying to fly to the US from Germany?

All advice gratefully received.

Comment: You can replace your passport in a day if you are in the UK. If he is a UK citizen then he shouldn't need a visa for the USA. Why do you think he needs a visa?

Comment: @DJClayworth he might if he's had any involvement with several particular countries recently. Also, op might mean an ESTA, as many many people see that as a visa - to all intents and purposes, it is very similar.

Comment: @Moo Yes, all those are possible. That's why I asked.

Comment: Hi everyone. He won’t have a full passport only emergency travel docs and you don’t appear to be able to use this without a full visa rather than vwp. Can he apply for an esta with ETD?

Comment: Also U.K. passport office said he can’t use passport in a day if passport is lost or stolen. Plus he is stuck in Germany at the moment awaiting the ETDs

Comment: "UK Emergency Travel Documents (ETDs) aren’t valid for entry into the United States or transit through the United States under the Visa Waiver Programme. If you’re planning to enter or transit through the US using an ETD you must apply for a visa from the nearest US embassy or consulate before you travel, or hold a valid lawful permanent resident card (often referred to as a ‘green card’), which you must have with you on arrival."  https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/usa/entry-requirements

Comment: @DJClayworth VWP requires a biometric passport.

Comment: @Moo VWP requires a biometric passport.

Comment: @phoog I am aware of that, I was merely musing about possible reasons for asking.

Comment: @Moo it seems odd to muse about that when we know that Kate's husband won't have a biometric passport.

Comment: @phoog again, something the op might not know, and as such doesn't modify my musing at all. Don't confuse musing about reasons for asking with reasons for the question not being valid.

Comment: @Moo sure.  It is however odd that your didn't mention the most obvious reason among your musings.

Comment: @Moo I'm not sure what you're referring to as "putting down." I was trying to clarify a situation that appeared to be unclear for some people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The US Department of State [reports a processing time](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/wait-times.html) of four calendar days in Munich, so getting a visa there next week seems likely.

London currently reports seven days for visitor visas, so it's probably best to apply in Munich for that reason, but it should not matter where he flies from.